# jQuery + PHP Datatables Server Side Processing with Column Filtering

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have implemented SSP with jQuery Datatables and global filter but after a review I wanted to implement specific column filtering but I am having issues. This is the code I have so far:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   initAdultTable();
});

function initAdultTable () {
  return tablessp = $('#members').DataTable({
    url: '<?php echo site_url("members"); ?>',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    pageLength: 25,
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000,5000], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]],
    deferRender: true,
    dom: 'flBrtip',
    retrieve: true,
    ordering: true,
    order: [[0, "desc"]],
    language: {
        "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
        "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
        "info": "Showing _MAX_ entries",
        "infoEmpty": "No records available",
        "infoFiltered": "( from _TOTAL_ total records)"
    },
    scrollx: true, 
    sScrollX: "100%",

    columns: [{data: "id"}, {data: "first_name"}, {data: "middle_name"},{data: "last_name"} , {data: "phone_number"} , {data: "company_location"} ,{data: "parent"} ,{data: "agency_location"} , {data: "Age"} , {data: "gender"} , {data: "education_level"} , {data: "marital_status"} , {data: "office_pos"} , {data: "email"}, {data: "membership_status"}, {data: "active_status"}, {data: "street_address"}, {data: "postcode"}, {data: "action"} ]
});
}

function searchAdultData(){

    var tablessp = initAdultTable();

    office_position_id = $('#office_position_id').val();
    membership_status_id = $('#membership_status_id').val();
    agency_id = $('#agency_id').val();
    company_id = $('#company_id').val();

    tablessp
    .columns(14).search(office_position_id)
    .columns(16).search(membership_status_id)
    .columns(7).search(agency_id)
    .columns(5).search(company_id)
    .draw(); 

}

function resetAdultData(){
    var tablessp = initAdultTable();
    $('#membersForm')[0].reset();

    tablessp.search('');
    tablessp.draw();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12"> 

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-brand--icon" id="kt_search" onClick="searchAdultData();" style="width:100%;">
                            <span>
                                <i class="la la-search"></i>
                                <span>Search</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-warning--icon" id="kt_reset" onClick="resetAdultData();" style="width:100%;">
                            <span>
                                <i class="la la-close"></i>
                                <span>Reset</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

After trying many implementations this is the one that got me closest to what I wanted to do. Initially it was giving me an error that tablessp was not defined, so I put the initializing of the table into a function and returned its value. On load the datatable renders as expected but when I search It gives me this error:

> Cannot set property 'data' of null

PHP:

```
<?php 
       if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            /** this will handle datatable js ajax call * */
            /** get all datatable parameters * */

            $search = $this->input->get('search') ;/** search value for datatable  * */
            $offset = $this->input->get('start') ;/** offset value * */
            $limit = $this->input->get('length') ;/** limits for datatable (show entries) * */
            $order = $this->input->get('order') ;/** order by (column sorted ) * */
            $column = array('members.id', 'first_name', 'middle_name','last_name','phone_number','company_location','parent','agency_location','Age','gender','education_level','marital_status','office_pos','email', 'membership_status','active_status','street_address','postcode', 'action');/**  set your data base column name here for sorting* */

            //$column = array('id');/**  set your data base column name here for sorting* */
            $type = '';
            $orderColumn = isset($order[0]['column']) ? $column[$order[0]['column']] : 'members.id';
            $orderDirection = isset($order[0]['dir']) ? $order[0]['dir'] : 'desc';
            $ordrBy = $orderColumn . " " . $orderDirection;

            if (!empty($search['value'])) {
                $type="search";

                // RESULT SET WHEN QUERYING
                $sql = "SELECT members.`id`,`first_name`, `middle_name`,`last_name`, picture `Photo`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_birth, CURDATE()) as `Age`, gender, marital_status, members.phone_number, members.email, setting_company.name as `company_name`, setting_office_position.title `office_pos`, setting_company_group._description `company_location`, setting_agency_parent.description `parent`, setting_agency_group.description `agency_location`, street_address , postcode, setting_occupation.title `job`, setting_membership_status.title `membership_status` , active_status, education_level FROM members
                ** VARIOUS_JOINS_GOES HERE **
                WHERE members.company_id = '$company_id' AND (members.membership_status != 10) AND members.age_group = 'Adults'
                AND (CONCAT(members.first_name, ' ' , members.middle_name, ' ', members.last_name  ) LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_company_group.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_office_position.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_membership_status.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_agency_group.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')

                order by " . $ordrBy . " limit $offset,$limit";

                // QUERY FOR COUNT OF ROWS
                $sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as `filtered` FROM members
                ** VARIOUS_JOINS_GOES HERE **
                WHERE members.company_id = '$company_id' AND (members.membership_status != 10) AND members.age_group = 'Adults'
                AND (CONCAT(members.first_name, ' ' , members.middle_name, ' ', members.last_name  ) LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_company_group.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_office_position.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_membership_status.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')
                OR (setting_agency_group.id LIKE '%" . $search['value'] . "%' AND members.company_id = '$company_id')

                order by " . $ordrBy;

                $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                $result2 = $this->db->query($sql2)->row();
                $count = $result2->filtered;
            } else {
                DEFAULT DATA WITHOUT FILTER HERE 
            }
```

I removed some of the columns and parts of the queries to make it easier and more practical for someone to review.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I can see that the data i'm filtering is being added to the request under `column[x][search][value] = 'search value'`, I can assume I am doing something wrong on the PHP side?

Side Note: Before anyone points out I know some security work needs to be done here.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of browser debug tools? Please check the response of the server when you search. is the data attribute filled with an array of objects with needed attributes?

Comment: When the request goes to the server, the correct columns are populated in the json as I said above. But when the response is returned it just returns the full dataset without filtering. Some other implementations I have done just returned an error in console saying null data

Comment: I assume that all request fields, primary `$search['value']`, are filled. Please check that `$sql` is what you expect and that the correct branch of the if is executed. Is public demo of the code (with sample data) possible?

Comment: does the returning data in required format of json

Answer (score 0):

In your function: `initAdultTable()` you are not returning the Datatable API instead you are always returning true. `return a = whatever;` will not return value of `a`, it will return `boolean: true` because it successfully assigned the value to `a`.

It works the first time because you called initAdultTable() on document ready. It gets the data and fills the table.

Second time you are expecting it to return the dataset that you wish to sort/filter but it just fills all the data just like the first time and returns `true`. You are trying to sort a `boolean`, hence the error.

Change the function `initAdultTable()` like this...

```
function initAdultTable() {
  return $('#members').DataTable({
     //......
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign data table to global variable `tablessp` so it can be accessed inside other functions as and when required.

Here is code that might be helpful to you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// define variable for table globally
var tablessp;
$(document).ready(function() {
   initAdultTable();
});

function initAdultTable () {
    // do not return anything here
    tablessp = $('#members').DataTable({
        // Your code
    });
}

function searchAdultData() {
    office_position_id = $('#office_position_id').val();
    membership_status_id = $('#membership_status_id').val();
    agency_id = $('#agency_id').val();
    company_id = $('#company_id').val();

    tablessp
        .columns(14).search(office_position_id)
        .columns(16).search(membership_status_id)
        .columns(7).search(agency_id)
        .columns(5).search(company_id)
        .draw(); 
}

function resetAdultData() {
    $('#membersForm')[0].reset();

    tablessp.search('');
    tablessp.draw();    
}
</script>
```